# WordPress .htaccess: How to remove directory from url?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

My site url was originally like this:
http://www.example.com/folder

I'm trying to get rid of www and /folder, as well as redirecting http to https.
My .htaccess currently looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =off   [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^example\.com/folder$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

http://www.example.com/folder/mypage should then redirect to https://example.com/mypage but I have no idea how to remove /folder. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a directory you'd need a line like this:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```